# Django variable increment in views

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm new to Django and can't figure out what's wrong.

I want to display one row of a database after another, which should change after pressing a button. The purpose is to translate vocabulary and check if it's right.

This is my view:

```
counter = 3
def learn(request):
    obj = Vokabel.objects.filter(pk=counter)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=addE(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            temp1 = request.POST.get('elearn')
            for i in obj:
                if temp1 == i.eVok:
                    counter = counter + 1
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/learnnext/')
                else:       
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/learn/')
    else:
        form = addE()
        return render(request, 'learn.html', {'form' : form, 'obj' : obj})
```

And my forms:

```
class addV(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Vokabel
    fields= ['eVok', 'dVok']

class addE(forms.Form):
    elearn = forms.CharField(label='Uebersetzung', max_length= 100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
```

However this returns the following error to me:

```
local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: This is not so related to Django. Where was `counter` first defined and what  value is being incremented?

Comment: And why do you increment counter anyway? You're not using it anywhere. Also, think about what will happen when your site has multiple users.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However I just want counter to be incrementet everytime i hit a button. Multiple user managment is way above my skill level at the moment anyway. This vaiable counter I then want to use in order to retrive evey vocable in my database and display it one after another. @Moses Koledoye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is there because you did not specify that you want to use global variable counter, so from the parser's point of view you are trying to use a value of a local variable counter before you assign any value to it. Look up `global` keyword for more info. But that is besides the point.

Django is not a continuous process. It seems to be common misconception to think of your Django code as a continuously running program. It is not. Django app lifecycle is between the moment request is received and the moment response is sent. You cannot really rely on your counter variable staying put. There are a few ways to deal with this depending on your particular constraints. If you want each user to have their own counter, you might want to use sessions and set counter as a session key (here is a [doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)). If you want the counter to be global across all user sessions you could use the cache API to store and update its value (again, relevant [doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#basic-usage)).

Comment: Thank you very much  ^v^